# How to get IP addr from MAC

Tags: nmap

I'm trying to connect to a second-hand external wifi camera.  It has an ethernet slot and a sticker with the MAC address but no other branding or model/serial numbers.

I am trying to find its IP address.

My current plan is to connect an ethernet cable directly between my machine and this camera, then scan all reserved private IPv4 ranges with `nmap`:

```
ip addr add 10.0.0.1/8 dev eno2
ip addr add 172.16.0.1/12 dev eno2
ip addr add 192.168.0.1/16 dev eno2

nmap -sn 192.168.0.0/16 172.16.0.0/12 10.0.0.0/8
```

But this could take a long time (I'm guessing about 74 hours) and I can't be sure that this device isn't using IPv6.  Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could install a `DHCP` server and then check its logs for the IP address the camera gets.

Alternatively you could run `tcpdump` to see any devices talking on your LAN.

---

You can monitor the ethernet port with `tcpdump`:

```
sudo tcpdump -A -i eno2
```

In my case, I got the following which seems to confirm that the device has no IP and is indeed communicating (MAC was correct)

```
11:26:29.247184 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:Xx (oui Unknown), length 291
```

---

Install and configure a DHCP server:

```
sudo apt install isc-dhcp-server
sudo ip addr add 192.168.2.1/24 dev eno2
```

add the following to `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  range 192.168.2.10 192.168.2.20;
}
```

Set `INTERFACESv4="eno2"` in `/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`.

```
sudo systemctl restart ics-dhcp-server.service
```

Now check the journal to see if any IP addresses were issued:

```
sudo journalctl -u isc-dhcp-server.service
Nov 24 11:31:11 simswe24 systemd[1]: Started LSB: DHCP server.
Nov 24 11:31:12 simswe24 dhcpd[14238]: DHCPOFFER on 192.168.2.10 to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (BV-CAM06S) via eno2
Nov 24 11:31:12 simswe24 dhcpd[14238]: DHCPREQUEST for 192.168.2.10 (172.16.0.1) from xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (BV-CAM06S) via eno2
Nov 24 11:31:12 simswe24 dhcpd[14238]: DHCPACK on 192.168.2.10 to xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx (BV-CAM06S) via eno2
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do a broadcast ping on the interface to which you have the device connected:

```
$ sudo ping -I enp0s31f6 -b 255.255.255.255
WARNING: pinging broadcast address
PING 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255) from 192.168.86.32 enp0s31f6: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.86.23: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=6.04 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.86.43: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=190 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.86.135: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=192 ms
```

If you're directly connected to that device, then ideally the only response you get will be from that device, and that response will include the IP address.

**Edit**

Since there's some question about the efficacy of this suggestion, I thought it might be valuable to add a little detail about the results that I demonstrated above.

First, let me emphasize that I did *not* receive a response from every device on my network, so this suggestion clearly won't work for every type of device.

Next, let's look more closely at one of the remote hosts from which I did receive a response:

```
64 bytes from 192.168.86.135: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=192 ms
```

What's that hosts' MAC address?

```
$ arp -n | grep 192.168.86.135
192.168.86.135       ether   50:c7:bf:b1:f5:9b   C       enp0s31f6
```

What's the manufacturer of that device?

```
$ grep -i 50c7bf /usr/share/arp-scan/ieee-oui.txt
50C7BF  TP-LINK TECHNOLOGIES CO.,LTD.
```

My guess is that's one of the smart plugs in my home.

In short, some devices may respond and some devices may not, depending on their network stack and security configuration.  Without knowing those detail for your camera, it's impossible to say definitively whether this will work or not for your case.

Comment: Broadcast ping hasn't worked in Linux for ages. It's considered insecure. ```ping -I enp3s0 -b 255.255.255.255
WARNING: pinging broadcast address
PING 255.255.255.255 (255.255.255.255) from 192.168.1.252 enp4s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 255.255.255.255 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 5120ms
```

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov that's odd -- it worked for me. I didn't hand-craft the example above, that was from a _real_ invocation of the command.  I certainly don't deny that it's considered insecure, but for this specific use case, it might be a viable option.

Comment: Also, it's simple to try, and if it doesn't happen to work the OP has invested very little in trying.

Comment: Checked on Debian 10 and Debian 11 machines, wireless and ethernet devices on networks with several known devices.  Like @ArtemS.Tashkinov I had 100% packet loss.  But it was worth a try!